# Reflection finding method with Generic Type withing Parameterized Class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, methods

I have a class with following signature:

```
public class MultipleSorting<T extends Enum<?>> {
    private Class<T> criteriaType;
    private T selectedCriteria;

    public MultipleSorting(Class<T> criteriaType) {
        super();
        this.criteriaType = criteriaType;
    }    

    public void setSelectedCriteria(T selectedCriteria) {
        this.selectedCriteria = selectedCriteria;
    }

    public T getSelectedCriteria() {
        return selectedCriteria;
    }

    public Class<T> getCriteriaType(){
        return criteriaType;
    }

    public void setCriteriaType(Class<T> criteriaType){
        this.criteriaType = criteriaType;
    }
}
```

I am instantiating it as `new MultipleSorting(ArticleSortField.class);`. Here `ArticleSortField` is an `Enum`. Now from another method within `MultipleSorting` when I am trying to get the method `setSelectedCriteria` through reflection as:

```
Method setSelectedCriteriaMethod = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelectedCriteria",getCriteriaType());
```

The `setSelectedCriteriaMethod` is returning `null`. After debugging I found that the `getCriteriaType()` is returning the class `ArticleDortField` but the argument type of the `setSelectedCriteria` method is `Enum`, that is why reflection is returning `null`.

Also if I change the signature of the `MultipleSorting` as `public class MultipleSorting<T>` then the `T` of `setSelectedCriteria` is becoming `Object`.

- How can I fix the issue?
- Is this happening due to type erasure? I thought that `T` will be replaced by `ArticleDortField`. But couldn't understand why it is behaving like this. How exactly type erasure works? Do they replace the generic type with the concrete implementation?

Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible fix for your issue might be to look for the "setSelectedCriteria" `Method` by calling `getClass().getDeclaredMethod(...)` with the desired type, then with its super type, and walking up the class hierarchy until you found a matching method. It's not a very beautiful solution but it might do the trick.

And yes, this is caused by type erasure. Once your code is compiled, there is no `<T>` but just `Object`, there is no `<T extends Enum<?>>` but just `Enum`. The type safety is something that is checked by the compiler, but not enforced by the JVM.